# INSERT block of rows from a column from one table to another table

Tags: mysql

How do I insert a block of rows from a column from one table and insert that block at a certain place in another table? See screenshot

[image]

So, what i need to do is to insert the block of missing data in "aktier" from aktie2. The "datum"-column between the tables must match exactly. So - is it possible to do this at once (without a loop) ?

I want to copy "aktie"-column (table aktie2) to aktie2-column (table aktier)

Comment: What would the table look like afterwards

Comment: @Strawberry - the column aktie2 in "aktier" will have all its values that now is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this by `update join` query using `concat` function like this

```
update aktier 
join aktie2 on aktie2.id = aktier.uid
set aktier.aktie2 = concat (aktier.aktie2, aktie2.aktie )
```

Comment: many thanks, but its should be matched on "datum" that is syntax changed to **... aktie2.datum = aktier.datum** (not id)

Comment: @java It seems to me that using the key `id` is the way to go here since dates may not be unique across id values.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing your screenshot, it looks like you are looking for an UPDATE, not an INSERT:

```
update aktier
set aktie2 = (select aktie from aktie2 where aktie2.datum = aktier.datum)
where aktie2 is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your scenerio it is an update case not an insert.

```
    URPDATE aktier
    SET aktie2 = (SELECT aktie FROM aktie2 where aktie2.id = aktier.id)
    where aktie2 is null;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.